# "Updating" webpage through jQuery and localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, contenteditable

So I have a home page that I created using HTML. I run it off my computer by opening the HTML file. I'm trying to add a feature that allows me to edit it from the page (using `content-editable` or `append`), not the source code. To achieve this, I came up with using `localStorage` to hold the updated version of the webpage, and loading the page from that updated version. See [here](http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/06/allowing-users-to-edit-text-content-with-html5/). (Theoretically, I would periodically update the source code from the `localStorage` version so it's all matched up.)

However, when I tried it, my page won't update. I have a version saved into `localStorage`, but it seems as if the program can't overwrite the that version, or something similar.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>SCSS | Projects</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="home page heading style.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="home page projects style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="save script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>


<body onload="checkEdits()">
<div id="everything">

<div class="box">
<a href="who am i.html"><div class="img"><img src="who am i.png" /></div></a>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="title">Who Am I?</div>
    <div class="description">A project for English class describing who I am through different medias and explained by unit questions.</div>
</div>
<div class="notes" contenteditable="true">Complete.</div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="back-to-top" onclick="saveEdits()">S</a>

</div><!--End everything-->
</body>
```

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
function saveEdits() {

//get the editable element
var edited = document.getElementById("everything");

//get the edited element content
var userVersion = edited.innerHTML;

//save the content to local storage
var localStorage.Edits = userVersion;

}

function checkEdits() {

//find out if the user has previously saved edits
if(localStorage.Edits != null)

document.getElementById("everything").innerHTML = localStorage.Edits;

}
```

But my page doesn't actually work right; it doesn't load the updated version. From viewing `localStorage`, it seems as if it's not even saving it properly.

Why doesn't it work? How can I fix it? Is there something conceptually incorrect about my plan? Any help would be appreciated; thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `localStorage` you can `get/setItem` e.g.

```
function saveEdits() {

  //get the editable element
  var edited = document.getElementById("everything");

  //get the edited element content
  var userVersion = edited.innerHTML;

  //save the content to local storage
  localStorage.setItem('Edits', userVersion);

}

function checkEdits() {

  //find out if the user has previously saved edits
  var savedEdits = localStorage.getItem('Edits');

  if (savedEdits != null) {
    document.getElementById("everything").innerHTML = savedEdits;
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage

You might also notice that jQuery is not used/required for this code...

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! And yep, I left the iQuery in the title...Whoops.